# Cannot change baud rate in C# even if the port is closed and reopened after setting new baud rate

Tags: c#, serial-port, baud-rate

I have a similar question in the forum. [Change baud rate in C# without closing connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992530/change-baud-rate-in-c-without-closing-connection) . In that question i asked how to change the baud rate without closing the port. Someone suggested me to close and reopen the port but i already tried that before asking that question, it also didn't work. Closing and reopening the port is not important to me ( the third party software which is also talking with the same meter, was not closing the port when i monitor it so i asked that question thinking that it maybe a clue)  important thing is changing baud rate of the device. I am waiting for help. Thank you for your time..
Ferda Ozdemir

Comment: Can you give specifics about the device you are connecting to please?

Comment: Hi Dbasnett, I am connecting to a electronic electric meter. It starts with 300 Baud then it goes to 4800 Baud. There is another software for that device. I run that software and monitor the port. I see that it send ACK command to the meter to change the baud rate to 4800 and it continues to read. But in my software i send the same command to the meter and i can not communicate with it any more.

Comment: Have you tried just running your program at 4800?

Comment: Yes I tried it. In that way i couldn't get any response from meter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My serialport object was defined in my main form. I was sending to my reading function as a parameter. And do everything there like opening port, setting baud rate, writing data, closing port etc. But I was running this function in  another thread. When i try to change baud rate i think there exists a delay or something so i can not change baudrate properly. Then i changed my code and now i can change the baud rate and go on with other things. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You have to wait until the driver had a chance to empty the write buffer.  At 300 baud that takes a while, it only writes 30 bytes per second.